# CSS Content Flex

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to create a table where each column header contains a column name and a sort symbol.
To do this, I'm using bootstrap.
You can see my code below:

```css
.glyphicon-menu-down,
.glyphicon-menu-up {
  display: block!important;
  font-size: 9px;
}

th {
  background-color: #0C69E8;
}

th {
  color: white;
}

th .align {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" align="center">
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col" class="pointer">
          <div style="float:left; margin-right:10px;">First</div>
          <div>
            <div id="up" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up"></div>
            <div id="down" class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></div>
          </div>
        </th>
        <th scope="col" class="pointer">
          <div class="align">
            <div style="margin-right:10px">Last</div>
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up">
              <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>

        <th scope="col" class="pointer">
          <div class="align">
            <div style="margin-right:10px">Handle</div>
            <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-up">
              <div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">3</th>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
```

My solution is to use a display flex on the headers column and 2 bootstrap glyphicons. If I don't use a flex display, the elements are not on the same line.
I think my solution is not really clean so if someone had a better solution, I'll take it.
Could someone give me his opinion on the code?

Thanks for any help